# How to create a user page for wordpress？

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

In Wordpress there is an author.php template file that you can use to display author information. I am wondering if there is a way to create a template file to display a users information (any role), even if they are not an author to any post, but is a registered user.

Answer (score 0):

By default, wordpress is handling profile page for authors only.

In your case, registered user seems any subscriber or editor also have profile page.

To handle that scenario you need to add plug-in.

- [User Profile Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/user-profile-page/)
- [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/)